# how to rearrange matrix equation to have unknown in vector form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I am looking for the name/type of following equations:
$$\dot{\theta}\dot{J} = \ddot{x} - J\ddot{\theta}$$
here the unknown is $J \in R^{m \times n}$, $x \in R^{m \times 1}$, $\theta \in R^{n \times 1}$. I've found this equation is same type with 1st order non-homogeneous matrix differential equation:
$$dx/dt = Ax + b$$

However, in this case, $x$ unknown is a vector, So my original equation should need some rearrangement

I frequently need to deal with such matrix equations. I am wondering if there is any reference on such matrix rearrangement. It will be more thorough if I can have a general view of these solutions, not just to pick up suggestions from SE at one specific problem

Thanks a lot!

Edit01: one solution

$ \dot{J}={(\ddot{x}-J\ddot{\theta})\dot{\theta}^TW(t)}/\dot{\theta}^TW(t)\dot{\theta} $

Comment: I see the problem with this system: $J$ has $mn$ unknown entries, but we have only $m$ equations. Are you sure that everything is OK?

Comment: yes, it is! the author also states that there is no unique solution and he picks up one solution like in my new editing. but I would like to know general approaches to these types of equation

Comment: Maybe you can provide a reference to the article that you're studying? I think that trick here is similar to some kind of pseudo-inverse: when you have system $Ax = b $ ($A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$), its solution also satisfies $A^{T} A x = A^{T}b$. The solution of latter can be found via usual inverse.

Comment: @Evgeny: it's equation (4)-(5) in "versatile visual servoing without knowledge of true Jacobian" - Koh Hosoda, a journal paper. Thanks for your response!

Comment: is there any further clue I can have to investigate about this equation?

Comment: I was thinking about it. There are two things that confuse me. The first thing is that notation is screwed in formula (5) of article (dimensions don't agree for matrix multiplication). The second thing is that my naive attempt had no success (when $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $\theta \theta^{T}$ is $n \times n$ matrix, but it has rank 1 therefore non-invertible). I'm still thinking about how to address these issues.